# SML: syntax error: replacing LET with RAISE

Tags: sml

I'm writing a function, that takes date in (d, m, y) format. I need to count rez value, all of these +getNthInt function calls are adding certain elements from the list.

```
fun firstNewMoonInt ((d, m, y) : int * int * int) : int option =
  let
    if m = 1 orelse m = 2 then y - 1
    else y
    val rez = newStyleCorrection (d, m, y) * 100000 
    + getNthInt(thousandCorrection, y div 1000) 
    + getNthInt (hundredCorrection, y div 100 mod 10)
    + getNthInt (decadeCorrection, y mod 100 div 10)
    + getNthInt (yearCorrection, y mod 1000)
    + getNthInt (monthCorrection, m - 1)
    + getNthInt (calendarCorrection, y mod 4)
    rez - lastSmaller(rez - 100000, reductions)
  in
    if rez div 100000 <= 30 then SOME rez
    else NONE
  end
```

I'm getting two syntax errors:

```
2.3-2.6 Error: syntax error: replacing  LET with  RAISE
13.3 Error: syntax error: inserting  LET
```

Since I use all keywords for the constructions: let-in-end, if-then-else. I don't understand, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Hi Just a tip. I suggest that in order to debug this, you minimize the problem. I.e try to remove stuff until it works or is small enough. Now the function is quite complex and it's rather hard to spot the issue.

Comment: What do you expect the expressions `if m = 1 orelse m = 2 then y - 1 else y` and `rez - lastSmaller(rez - 100000, reductions)` to accomplish in a variable binding? You should probably review what a `let` block is for and what it can contain.

Comment: @molbdnilo basically if statement means that if month value equals 1 or 2, then i need to subtract 1 from the year value, otherwise year value stays the same. Only after checking this, I can start counting rez variable. After I performed a bunch of + operations, I need to grab the current rez value and subtract from it one more value that i get with function lastSmaller

Comment: Forget that assignment exists. In fact, forget that there are other programming languages that you've used - SML is fundamentally different from languages like Python and is easier learned without prejudice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Immediately inside a `let`, there should be a sequence of declarations. (Declarations are things like `val x = ...` or `fun f x = ...`). But in your code, there is an `if` which begins an expression.

You could fix this by making a new variable which is the result of the `if` expression:

```ml
let
  val new_y = 
    if m = 1 orelse m = 2 then y - 1
    else y

  val rez = ...
```

And then you will need to figure out where to use `new_y` in the rest of the code.

Note that there is a similar problem just a few lines further down:

```ml
rez - lastSmaller(rez - 100000, reductions)
```

This is an expression where there should be another declaration. You could also fix it the same way: `val new_rez = rez - lastSmaller (...)` and then use `new_rez` where appropriate below that.